# Accessing the Windows Downloads folder in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, filesystems

According to [this](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/05/21/winrt-folders-access/) article, we only have write access to the Downloads folder - this seems to be supported by what I've found.  Is there any way around this in WinRT?  I want to be able to iterate through the files in the downloads folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.downloadsfolder.aspx)'s the official documentation on the subject:

> All apps can create files and folders in the Downloads folder and can
>   access the files that they create. But apps can't access files in the
>   Downloads folder that they didn't create.
>
> When your app creates a file in the Downloads folder, other apps can't
>   interfere with or access your file unless the user explicitly gives
>   the other app access. The user can give another app access to your
>   file by selecting the file from the file picker. Your app can also use
>   the file picker to get access to the files in the Downloads folder
>   that it didn't create.

So, no: there's no way to enumerate or iterate through all the files in the folder without user intervention. You could it, though, if you get the user to select the folder with a `FolderPicker`:

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
foreach (var file in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
{
    // do something with each file
}
```

After you get the reference to `StorageFolder` you can even store it in `MostRecentlyUsedList` so that you can access it in the future without the user having to select it again:

```
var token = StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(folder);
```

You only need to store the returned token to get access to it again:

```
var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFolderAsync(token);
```